# EntityQuery condition on translation status

Tags: 8, database, i18n-l10n

Im currently using `Drupal::entityQuery()` to build a list of node.

I need to be able to query only contentEntities that have a specific translation not published. I struggle because I don't know how to make a condition on an entity translated field/property.

to sum up:
**How to query all nodes that have 'de' translation AND which their 'de' translation are not published?**

Is there a way to do it with `Drupal::entityQuery()` or should I directly go with altering the query with `QueryInterface::addTag()` where I would be able to customize the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want.  Note that the id's will load the default language, you will need to use getTranslation(langCode) to get the translated node.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 0);
$query->condition('type', YOUR_TYPE);
$query->condition('langcode', 'de');
$ids = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

> $query->condition('langcode', 'de');

This condition gets only nodes, that have last translation to 'de' language or created on 'de' language and didn't translate to another language (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3092835)

You can use this solution:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 0);
$query->condition('type', YOUR_TYPE);
$ids = $query->execute();

//And then check if entity has needed translation:
$language = 'de';
$list = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($ids);
foreach ($list as $key => $node) {
  if (!$node->hasTranslation($language)) {
    unset($list[$key]);
  }
  else {
    $list[$key] = $node->getTranslation($language);
  }
}
```

As a result, you have a correct list of entities that have relation to requested language.